# Как получить доступ к расширенной модели User?

Tags: django

Есть модель которая расширяет User:

```
class AdvancedUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.TextField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    patronymic = models.TextField(max_length=60, blank=True)
    confirmed_email = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    confirmed_phone = models.BooleanField(default = False)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        AdvancedUser.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
 def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     instance.advanceduser.save()#AdvancedUser
```

Пытаюсь получить к ней доступ:

```
new_user = User.objects.create(username=str(uuid.uuid4()), email=email,  first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name'])  
new_user.set_password(password)
new_user.advenceduser.confirmed_email = True
new_user.save()
```

Получаю -

> 'User' object has no attribute 'advenceduser'

Пробую так:

```
password = form.cleaned_data['password']
new_user = User.objects.create(username=str(uuid.uuid4()), email=email,  first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name'])  
advenced_user = users = User.objects.get(email=email).select_related('advenceduser')
new_user.set_password(password)
new_user.save()
```

Получаю:

> 'User' object has no attribute 'select_related'

Еще так:

```
new_user = User.objects.create(username=str(uuid.uuid4()), email=email,  first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name'])  
advenced_user = AdvancedUser(user=new_user)
new_user.set_password(password)
new_user.save()
```

Получаю:

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_advanceduser_user_id_key"
>   DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(15) already exists.

Получается  `advenced_user = AdvancedUser(user=new_user)` создает новую запись?
Делал по [этому](https://tproger.ru/translations/extending-django-user-model/#var2) гайду.

Там приведен пример с изменением данных с помощью форм. А можно без них к этой модели обращаться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для создания пользователей рекомендуется использовать [метод менеджера](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user)  `.create_user()`.

```
# ...
user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email, first_name=first_name)
```

Дальше расширенный профиль можно будет получить так:

```
advanced = AdvancedUser.objects.filter(user=user).first()
```

`.filter()` и `.first()` используются для того, чтобы в случае отсутствия профиля - вернуло `None`, а не ошибку `AdvancedUser.DoesNotExist`.